# How can I cancel a process that is already running before creating another one in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA code, I have a button that triggers the "UpdateWorksheet" sub. This sub updates a range and schedules another update for a later time using the "Application.OnTime" method. However, I want to be able to cancel the scheduled update if the button is clicked again before the scheduled time.

How can I cancel the scheduled update and ensure that a new one is created with the updated time?

```
Sub UpdateWorksheet()
    ' Get the button that called this sub
    Dim btn As Shape
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    ' Get the text of the button
    Dim buttonText As String
    buttonText = btn.TextFrame.Characters.Text

    ' Update the range immediately
    Call UpdateRange(buttonText)
    
    ' Schedule the next update for the time specified in the "preflop" cell
    Dim preflopTime As Integer
    preflopTime = Range("preflop").Value
    
    ' Convert the time value from seconds to a value in days and hours for use in the "Application.OnTime" method
    Dim timeValue As Variant
    timeValue = TimeSerial(0, 0, preflopTime)

    ' Cancel any previously scheduled update with the name "SchedulePreflop"
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime Now, Procedure:="SchedulePreflop", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Schedule the "SchedulePreflop" sub to run after the specified time
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + timeValue, Procedure:="SchedulePreflop", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub SchedulePreflop()
    ' Call the "UpdateRange" function with the parameter "PREFLOP"
    Call UpdateRange("PREFLOP")
End Sub

Function UpdateRange(buttonText As String)
    ' Update the "spot" cell with the button text
    Range("spot").Value = buttonText
    
    ' Copy the range from the "Database" worksheet to the "Ranger" worksheet
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("Database").Range(buttonText)
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Ranger").Range("range")
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to cancel a previously-scheduled run, you need to provide the exact time the run was scheduled for, so typically you'd use a global variable to capture that value so you can re-use it when cancelling.  For example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-stop-applicationontime-loop/08d7cc43-ab58-4c8e-9a53-6d140950a824

Comment: [Quote:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) *Set Schedule to False to clear a procedure previously set with the same Procedure and EarliestTime values.*

Comment: Solved with global var! Ty guys!